# Different Mysql date Results On website and in PHPmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, date

I wants to select rows which are less than with **today date**.

In database my date column is saving data in **unix time stamp**.

I am running on following query with php and mysql. (*this query should show 1 row as i have 1 result in the database, but it is showing two rows.*)

```
SELECT * from products where seller_id ='1' and FROM_UNIXTIME(marketing_end_date,'%Y-%m-%d') < CURRENT_DATE();
```

But when i run above query in phpmyadmin it retrun **one row**( my desired result).

Here is my code which is reading data from mysql.

```
function get_sellerenddateproducts($admin,$seller_id,$limit_per_page,$start_index){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where(array('seller_id' => $seller_id));
    $this->db->where("FROM_UNIXTIME(marketing_end_date,'%Y-%m-%d') <","CURRENT_DATE()");
    $this->db->limit($limit_per_page, $start_index);
    $this->db->order_by('id','desc');
    $query = $this->db->from($this->_table_name)->get();
    $arr = $query->result_array();
    //echo $this->db->last_query(); die();
    return $arr;
}
```

**Question**

Why same query show different results ? How to get correct results?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to display the information.

Comment: @NigelRen Sorry i didnot get you, which code you wants to see php code or mysql function ?

Comment: The code which reads the data from the SQL and displays it in your application.

Comment: @NigelRen added the code

Comment: @HamzaZafeer Hey have you tried to echo and check your select query on php? You can then run that query on phpmyadmin and see if it really return 2 results

Comment: @NcXNaV Yes after echo query,, i directly run the query in phpmyadmin, then it shows 1 row, means correct result, but when run using my code it shows two rows means wrong results.

Comment: @NcXNaV `SELECT * from products where seller_id ='1' and FROM_UNIXTIME(marketing_end_date,'%Y-%m-%d') < CURRENT_DATE();
` this is echo result of the query..and provide correct result in phpmyadmin

Comment: Okay I see, both query done using the same user account right? All the same, except different results?

Comment: @NcXNaV yes same users

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234229/discussion-between-hamza-zafeer-and-ncxnav).

Comment: all your servers are on the same timezone right?

Comment: I think both are on same time zone, but for sure how can i check both are same ?

Answer (score 0):

`MySQL` actually stores `datetime` data type fields internally as UTC.

However, `PhpMyAdmin` shows you the dates using the `server default time`.

Use this line to detect TimeZone of your MySQL Server:

```
SELECT @@system_time_zone;
```

For example, try adding this line before PhpMyAdmin SQL statement:

```
Set time_zone = '+00:00';
```

This sets timezone to GMT/UTC, so that any further operations will use GMT.

Let me know if they return same result now :)

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my issue like below.

I create a variable like this.

```
$todaydate = date('Y-m-d');
```

and change my query from

```
$this->db->where("FROM_UNIXTIME(marketing_end_date,'%Y-%m-%d') <","CURRENT_DATE()");
```

to  this

```
$this->db->where("FROM_UNIXTIME(marketing_end_date,'%Y-%m-%d') <",$todaydate);
```

then it gives me correct result.